# how to change json order in retrofit android?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using retrofit library to post json data from my app to the server but the json key order i'm getting is not the order i want how to change it?

here's my retrofit postdata method where i have used gsonconverter

```
        // on below line we are creating a retrofit
        // builder and passing our base url
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://103.87.174.181/BatteryStation/api/BatteryStationAPI/")
                // as we are sending data in json format so
                // we have to add Gson converter factory
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson ))
                // at last we are building our retrofit builder.
                .build();
        // below line is to create an instance for our retrofit api class.
        RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);

        // passing data from our text fields to our modal class.
        DataModel modal = new DataModel(slotno, batteryid, voltage, current, power, parameterid, fault, alarm );

        // calling a method to create a post and passing our modal class.
        Call<DataModel> call = retrofitAPI.createPost(modal);
```

The strings which I am sending through modal class are

```
  String slo = String.valueOf(1);
  String bid = "12348149012";
  String vol = "0.15";
  String cur = "0.00";
  String pow = "0.00";
  String parameterid = "0A";
  String fault = "00";
  String alarm = "00";

 postData(slo,bid,vol,cur,pow,parameterid,fault,alarm);
```

and the json I'm getting on the server side is

```
{
    "alarm":"00",
    "batteryid":"12348149012",
    "current":"0.00",
    "fault":"00",
    "parameterid":"0A",
    "power":"0.00",
    "slotno":"1",
    "voltage":"0.15"
    
}
```

here's is my DataModal class

```
public class DataModel {



    private String slotno;
    private String parameterid;
    private String batteryid;
    private String voltage;
    private String current;
    private String power;
    private String alarm;
    private String fault;

    public DataModel(String slotno, String batteryid, String voltage, String current, String power, String parameterid, String fault, String alarm) {
        this.slotno = slotno;
        this.batteryid = batteryid;
        this.voltage = voltage;
        this.current = current;
        this.power = power;
        this.parameterid = parameterid;
        this.fault = fault;
        this.alarm = alarm;
    }

    public String getSlotno() {
        return slotno;
    }

    public void setSlotno(String slotno) {
        this.slotno = slotno;
    }

    public String getBatteryid() {
        return batteryid;
    }

    public void setBatteryid(String batteryid) {
        this.batteryid = batteryid;
    }

    public String getVoltage() {
        return voltage;
    }

    public void setVoltage(String voltage) {
        this.voltage = voltage;
    }

    public String getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(String current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public String getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(String power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public String getParameterid() {
        return parameterid;
    }

    public void setParameterid(String parameterid) {
        this.parameterid = parameterid;
    }

    public String getAlarm() {
        return alarm;
    }

    public void setAlarm(String alarm) {
        this.alarm = alarm;
    }

    public String getFault() {
        return fault;
    }

    public void setFault(String fault) {
        this.fault = fault;
    }



}
```

The order of this json is alphabetical, I want to change this order. I want parameter id to be first in the list. how to achieve that? please help... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." https://www.json.org/json-en.html, don't think this should matter

Comment: so it's not possible to make it in order?

Comment: i don't know if you can, i'm saying as a standard, it probably shouldn't be ordered, i don't really understand why you're trying to do this, nobody else has issues with the ordering of json, you're most likely trying to solve a problem which shouldn't exist

Comment: my php server side person who's getting that json wants it to be in order so that's why I'm trying

Comment: True, JSON objects are meant to be unordered, but the order _may have_ two cases when preserving the order **is** fine: 1) streamed reading (it may indicate a sort of bad design, but sometimes it saves) in very strict order, especially for large payloads (e.g., `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` uses a type designator field, but it also requires buffering a whole object into memory -- it would be easier if such a field would be the first one); 2) for documentation purposes preserving fields grouped according to the logical order either in DTOs or API specs.

Comment: @NiranjanAdhav Note that Gson, by default, **strictly preserves** the order of DTO fields according to how they are declared in their respective classes. Can you share your `DataModel` source code? What is the source you got the sorted JSON from (client side logging, network traffic logger, server side logging probably confused with something at the server side)? Additionally, may I know what is the reason of that person to want strict order for small objects where the order does not really matter at all?

Comment: @fluffy yes sure, I have edited the question and added my DataModal class You can look there thanks :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your DTO class. You can double-check it at your machine locally by doing `gson.toJson(...)`, so you'd see that Gson preserves the order you declared in the class. It is still unclear: where did you get the sorted JSON object from, and, if it's the server side, isn't then something wrong on your server thinking JSON payloads come sorted? And, really, why does server needs the strict order (I doubt that any PHP library requires that)?

Comment: no I don't get any sorted json object I'm just using post method in retrofit to send json to the server, they just want me to send json key/ value in order like they want parameter id in the first position..

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase: your client is working well (I do believe so), and they have something wrong at the server side (I seem to believe so). Again, their request for having entries in strict order does not make much sense unless it is justified by your server team explaining the real reason just because JSON standard tells that objects are _unordered_ by design therefore the order must never matter (even if someone wants it) + I still didn't get the info where the ordered JSON you provided comes from. I guess it's better to ask your server-side colleagues to remove that limitation.